# How to pass back value from JS to Python

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebchannel

I wanted to display a 2D Map with Python and then do something with the coordinates of the coursor in the Python code. I cant get the coordinates to the Python Part however.
Heres my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
import bs4

maphtml = '''

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, all" />    
    <script src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <title>WebGL Earth API - Side-by-side - Basic Leaflet compatibility</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js"></script>
    <script>
      var backend;
        new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            backend = channel.objects.backend;
        });
      function init() {
        var m = {};

        start_(L, 'L');
        start_(WE, 'WE');

        function start_(API, suffix) {
          var mapDiv = 'map' + suffix;
          var map = API.map(mapDiv, {
            center: [51.505, -0.09],
            zoom: 4,
            dragging: true,
            scrollWheelZoom: true,
            proxyHost: 'http://srtm.webglearth.com/cgi-bin/corsproxy.fcgi?url='
          });
          m[suffix] = map;

          //Add baselayer
          API.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
          }).addTo(map);

          //Add TileJSON overlay
          var json = {"profile": "mercator", "name": "Grand Canyon USGS", "format": "png", "bounds": [-112.26379395, 35.98245136, -112.10998535, 36.13343831], "minzoom": 10, "version": "1.0.0", "maxzoom": 16, "center": [-112.18688965, 36.057944835, 13], "type": "overlay", "description": "", "basename": "grandcanyon", "tilejson": "2.0.0", "sheme": "xyz", "tiles": ["http://tileserver.maptiler.com/grandcanyon/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"]};
          if (API.tileLayerJSON) {
            var overlay2 = API.tileLayerJSON(json, map);
          } else {
            //If not able to display the overlay, at least move to the same location
            map.setView([json.center[1], json.center[0]], json.center[2]);
          }

          //Add simple marker
          var marker = API.marker([json.center[1], json.center[0]]).addTo(map);
          marker.bindPopup(suffix, 50);
          marker.openPopup();

          //Print coordinates of the mouse
          map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML = e.latlng.lat + ', ' + e.latlng.lng;
            backend.print(e.latlng.lat)
          });
        }

        //Synchronize view
        m['L'].on('move', function(e) {
          var center = m['L'].getCenter();
          var zoom = m['L'].getZoom();
          m['WE'].setView([center['lat'], center['lng']], zoom);
        });
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      html, body{padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}
      #mapL, #mapWE {position:absolute !important; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
                     background-color: #fff; position: absolute !important;}
      #mapL {right: 0%;}
      #mapWE {left: 100%;}
      #coords {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="javascript:init()">
    <div id="mapL"></div>
    <div id="mapWE"></div>
    <div id="coords"></div>
  </body>
</html>
'''

class Browser(QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        QApplication.__init__(self, [])
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setWindowTitle("Serial GPS Emulator");

        self.web = QWebEngineView(self.window)

        self.web.setHtml(maphtml)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.window)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.web)

        self.window.show()
        self.exec()

Browser()
```

It would be good if the code would stay in one file but if its totally impossible to do it in one splitting it is acceptable.
I guess the first step in solving mny Problem would be to call a function from the HTML/JS part as backend.print("test") also doesnt work.
I also noticed that self.exec() Blocks the rest of the code, is there a way to execute any other code while the map is running? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see where in your code you have passed the backend.

In this case you must create a `Backend` class that can be injected, and for a method to be invoked it must be a slot, for this you must use the `pyqtSlot()` setting, the parameter that it receives depends on what you are sending it, in the case of the `e.latlng` is a `QJsonValue`. In the slot you must separate the necessary parts.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject, QJsonValue, pyqtSignal, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

maphtml = '''

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, all" />    
    <script src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <title>WebGL Earth API - Side-by-side - Basic Leaflet compatibility</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js"></script>
    <script>
      var backend;
        new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            backend = channel.objects.backend;
            console.log(backend);
        });
      function init() {
        var m = {};

        start_(L, 'L');
        start_(WE, 'WE');

        function start_(API, suffix) {
          var mapDiv = 'map' + suffix;
          var map = API.map(mapDiv, {
            center: [51.505, -0.09],
            zoom: 4,
            dragging: true,
            scrollWheelZoom: true,
            proxyHost: 'http://srtm.webglearth.com/cgi-bin/corsproxy.fcgi?url='
          });
          m[suffix] = map;

          //Add baselayer
          API.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
          }).addTo(map);

          //Add TileJSON overlay
          var json = {"profile": "mercator", "name": "Grand Canyon USGS", "format": "png", "bounds": [-112.26379395, 35.98245136, -112.10998535, 36.13343831], "minzoom": 10, "version": "1.0.0", "maxzoom": 16, "center": [-112.18688965, 36.057944835, 13], "type": "overlay", "description": "", "basename": "grandcanyon", "tilejson": "2.0.0", "sheme": "xyz", "tiles": ["http://tileserver.maptiler.com/grandcanyon/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"]};
          if (API.tileLayerJSON) {
            var overlay2 = API.tileLayerJSON(json, map);
          } else {
            //If not able to display the overlay, at least move to the same location
            map.setView([json.center[1], json.center[0]], json.center[2]);
          }

          //Add simple marker
          var marker = API.marker([json.center[1], json.center[0]]).addTo(map);
          marker.bindPopup(suffix, 50);
          marker.openPopup();

          //Print coordinates of the mouse
          map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML = e.latlng.lat + ', ' + e.latlng.lng;
            backend.print(e.latlng)
          });
        }

        //Synchronize view
        m['L'].on('move', function(e) {
          var center = m['L'].getCenter();
          var zoom = m['L'].getZoom();
          m['WE'].setView([center['lat'], center['lng']], zoom);
        });
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      html, body{padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}
      #mapL, #mapWE {position:absolute !important; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
                     background-color: #fff; position: absolute !important;}
      #mapL {right: 0%;}
      #mapWE {left: 100%;}
      #coords {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="javascript:init()">
    <div id="mapL"></div>
    <div id="mapWE"></div>
    <div id="coords"></div>
  </body>
</html>
'''


class Backend(QObject):
    positionChanged = pyqtSignal(float, float)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self.position = None, None
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)

    @pyqtSlot(QJsonValue)
    def print(self, val):
        coords = val.toObject()
        lat, lng = (coords[key].toDouble() for key in ("lat", "lng"))
        self.position = lat, lng
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.start()

    def on_timeout(self):
        self.positionChanged.emit(*self.position)


def foo(lat, lng):
    # this function will be called every second.
    print(lat, lng)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebEngineView()
    view.setWindowTitle("Serial GPS Emulator");

    backend = Backend(view)
    backend.positionChanged.connect(foo)
    channel = QWebChannel()
    channel.registerObject('backend', backend)
    view.page().setWebChannel(channel)
    view.setHtml(maphtml)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It will take me some time to understand your solution but its awesome to see that it works!

Comment: Can you also help me with implementing a infinite loop so I can do stuff with the coordinates every second? My Goal is to build  a GPS NMEA Emulator which sends out the coordinates of the cursor. That means it should send out a NMEA-sentence with the latest coordinate every second. I already figured out how to send Serial Data with pyserial so I would just have to call a Function sendNMEAmsg(lat,lng) every second. currently I can only execute a function on mosemove. How could you change that?

Comment: @KASA What coordinate do you want? if it is the mouse, in the case that the mouse was out of the screen, what coordinate would it send?

Comment: @KASA 
In addition it would not be better to send the information every time it is necessary, in this case every time the coordinate change, instead of every second.

Comment: The receiver of the Serial messages rquires a update every second, even if the Coordinates didnt change. I meant the coordinate on the map.

Comment: @KASA okay, I understand, what coordinates of the map ?, the map has innumerable coordinates.

Comment: I mean the coordinates of the cursor on the map (the coordinates that are being returned with your code)

Comment: @KASA okay, now I understand you better, but tell me if the cursor starts off the map, the coordinate will not exist, so what coordinate do you pass?

Comment: I guess then it would be best to pass the coordinate where the cursor was last registered. Can you give me some advice how to do this? I think a endless loop which returns the current coordinated instead of the on mousemove would be enough right? I tried implementing an example I found online but it didnt work...

Comment: @KASA 
The solution is not a loop, in a GUI the tasks are asynchronous, they can be repetitive, but not in a loop. the solution is to use signals but for this I need to see your code that sends the data, show me the while loop, I will have to modify it, but it is easier for me to do it if I know it.

Comment: I made a function which sends the coordinates over serial, can you modify the code that some dummy function sendNMEAmsg() gets executed every second with th coordinates as arguments? What while loop do you mean?

Comment: @KASA ok, I understand you, I was a bit confused, the solution I propose is that I will print the longitude and latitude every second, this starts when the first mouse position is received, if the mouse starts from outside the map it will not print until Put the mouse inside the map.

Comment: @KASA I have already updated my code, the `foo()` function is called every second.

Comment: Wow, its working Perfectly! Awesome! Thanks you very much!